# Проблема с правами на директорию у apache2

Tags: php, apache2, fedora, chmod, chown

После переустановки федоры 24 не могу создать не файл не каталог в директории.

```
[root@localhost /]# ls -ld /var/www/trade/public/tmp/
drwxrwxrwx. 2 apache apache 4096 окт 18 15:28 /var/www/trade/public/tmp/
```

> Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/trade/public/tmp/aaa.txt): failed
>   to open stream: Permission denied in...

Php говорит:

```
die(substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('/var/www/trade/public/tmp/')), -4) . '');
```

0777
Под рутом и обычным пользователем файлы и папки создаются.

Пример записи: 
`file_put_contents('/var/www/trade/public/tmp/aaa.txt', 'asd');`
Есть мысли, как это вылечить ?

Comment: посмотрите пути на все промежуточные папки в пути /var/www/..., они должны быть доступны на вход в них (атрибут 'x' для всех пользователей)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключи SElinux если включен и проверь еще раз запись в файл из PHP.
Файл настроек SElinux: */etc/selinux/config*.

Поставь на время вместо `SELINUX=enforcing` вот такую запись `SELINUX=disabled`